# Recover windows 8 UEFI Boot

Tags: windows-8, boot, partitioning, data-recovery, uefi

I have a Asus x202e notebook and I accidentally deleted the whole partition table while trying to install Ubuntu. I have recovered the partition table using testdisk tool. Now I see OS, Data, Restore partitions but can't boot to Windows 8. What would be the best and fastest way to restore/recover or reinstall Windows 8 on this Computer? This notebook doesn't have any cd/dvd drive and I don't need any data from this computer. Is there an way to boot from Restore Partition using any kind of live Usbflash Linuxro and do fresh Windows installation? I also deleted the UEFI boot while trying to restore the partition using testdisk tool.

Thanks.

EDIT: When this computer stats it loads BIOS. I tried F9 it doesn't help...

Comment: What happens if you press F9 when booting up? Don't you get into Recovery mode then and can reinstall the computer from scratch?

Comment: When computer starts it directly goes to BIOS. I have tried pressing F9 and it still goes to BIOS. I guess it is loading BIOS because  this hard drive doen't have bootable partition.

Comment: You say you "deleted the UEFI boot." If you're referring to the [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) then be aware that it is *required* to boot an EFI-based computer from a hard disk. Restore it and you may be able to boot again, or at least be most of the way there.

Comment: What is the best way to restore EFI? I can see it partition but i deleted the content...